# Приложение созданное в Android Studio при запуске на телефоне вылетает, а в эмуляторе работает отлично.Почему так происходит?

Tags: java, android, эмулятор

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipperMonitor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mon2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mon1" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipperKeybord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/keybord2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/keybord1" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NextKeybord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PrevKeybord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NextMonitor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="Далее" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PrevMonitor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NextMouse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PrevMouse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NextMat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PrevMat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextMenu1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevMenu1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextMenu2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevMenu2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextMenu3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevMenu3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Назад"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextMenu4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Далее" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevMenu4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="Монитор"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
package com.example.desksetup;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ViewFlipper flipperMonitor;
    ViewFlipper flipperKeybord;
    Button nextMonitor;
    Button prevMonitor;
    Button nextKeybord;
    Button prevKeybord;
    Button nextMouse;
    Button prevMouse;
    Button nextMat;
    Button prevMat;
    Button nextMenu1;
    Button prevMenu1;
    Button nextMenu2;
    Button prevMenu2;
    Button nextMenu3;
    Button prevMenu3;
    Button nextMenu4;
    Button prevMenu4;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flipperMonitor = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipperMonitor);
        flipperKeybord = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipperKeybord);
        nextMonitor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextMonitor);
        prevMonitor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PrevMonitor);
        nextKeybord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextKeybord);
        prevKeybord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PrevKeybord);
        nextMouse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextMouse);
        prevMouse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PrevMouse);
        nextMat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextMat);
        prevMat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PrevMat);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        nextMenu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextMenu1);
        prevMenu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevMenu1);
        nextMenu2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextMenu2);
        prevMenu2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevMenu2);
        nextMenu3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextMenu3);
        prevMenu3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevMenu3);
        nextMenu4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextMenu4);
        prevMenu4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevMenu4);
        

        nextMenu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Клавиатура");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        prevMenu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Монитор");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        nextMenu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Мишь");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        prevMenu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Монитор");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        nextMenu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Коврик");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        prevMenu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Клавиатура");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        nextMenu4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Коврик");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        prevMenu4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Мишь");
                nextMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMonitor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevKeybord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMouse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMouse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                nextMenu3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prevMenu3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                prevMenu4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

---

LogCat:

2020-07-07 21:17:29.149 17178-17178/? I/ample.desksetu: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-07-07 21:17:29.173 17178-17178/? W/ample.desksetu: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-07-07 21:17:29.219 17178-17185/? E/ample.desksetu: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2020-07-07 21:17:29.466 17178-17178/? W/ample.desksetu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-07-07 21:17:29.466 17178-17178/? W/ample.desksetu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-07-07 21:17:29.798 17178-17206/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-07-07 21:17:29.798 17178-17206/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-07-07 21:17:29.799 17178-17206/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-07-07 21:17:29.799 17178-17206/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-07-07 21:17:29.862 17178-17206/? E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

Comment: Причин может быть несколько сотен. Все не перечислить - кол-ва символов в поле ввода ответа не хватит. Скорее всего у вас банальный NPE из-за опечатки. Точно можно будет сказать только увидев лог падения

Comment: логи в студию. Подключите девайс к компьютеру и пришлите нам логи

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев Здравствуйте, мне нужна Ваша помощь, можете пожалуйста скинуть Вашу почту.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Здравствуйте, я обратился к Вам за помощю, написав Вам на почту, немогли бы Вы ответить, буду очень благгодарен.

Comment: @maasiliy, добрый день. Письмо видел. Однако будет гораздо эффективнее, если вы просто тут на сайте создадите вопрос - кто-нибудь что-то точно ответит. И потом этот вопрос ещё кому-то пригодится. А на почте оно затеряется и не будет полезно будущим поколениям.

Comment: @maasiliy, zhore-chebotarev@mail.ru. Пришлите ссылку на репозиторий я посмотрю